Am I using Euclid's Lemma in this informal argument for the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?
In a proof of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic in which Euclid's Lemma is used such as this one, I wonder why must we invoke Euclid's Lemma to prove uniqueness.
What's wrong with the following argument?  Suppose we have two distinct prime factorizations of a number $N$ so that $N = p_1 p_2 ... p_r = q_1 q_2 ... q_s$.  (In other words, if $N$ has a prime $p_i$ with multiplicity greater than one, then there will be enough $p_i$ to account for this multiplicity.)  The equation clearly implies that $p_1$ divides $N$, so $p_1$ must divide the product of $q$s as well, meaning we can cancel out $p_1$ from both sides.  Suppose that after cancelling all primes $p_i$, we end up with a certain $q_j$ that did not get cancelled.  This would mean that there is a divisor of $N$ that does not divide the product of $p$s, which is absurd.

You need to be a little more careful with the "meaning that we can cancel out..." part. How would you express this formally?
Since $p_1$ divides $\prod_{j=1}^{s}q_j$ then we can show almost immediately from the definition of $p_1$ being prime that there is some $j$ such that $p_1=q_j.$ However, proving this fact is exactly proving Euclid's Lemma!
Once we prove that fact or use Euclid's Lemma, we may without loss of generality assume that $j=1,$ because if not, we can simply re-index, and commutativity guarantees that the product will be unchanged.
Iterating this argument and using division will, indeed, allow you to reach the contradiction you mentioned. However, here is where we must be careful. If you just say something like "divide both sides by $p_1,$ then $p_2,$ and so on," without justifying the correspondence of factors, then you haven't proven that the factors are equal, just their products.
To see how it fails, let's consider a structure that has nonunique factorizations. Namely, consider the set $$\Bbb Z\left[\sqrt{5}\right]:=\left\{a+b\sqrt{5}\mid a,b\in\Bbb Z\right\},$$ under the usual addition and multiplication operations, and with the usual identity elements for each.
Then $$(2)(-2)=-4=\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right),$$ but there is no way to "cancel out" any factor of the either factorization, as none of them have multiplicative inverses in the structure.

Incidentally, it isn't necessary to proceed by contradiction. What you've shown with the iterative argument is that, without loss of generality, the first $r$ factors of the second factorization are identical to the corresponding factors of the first factorization, and so $r\leq s.$ However, a completely symmetric argument lets one show that the first $s$ factors of the first factorization are equal to the corresponding factors of the second factorization, so $s\leq r,$ so $r=s$ and each $p_i=q_i.$
If you want to get around the re-indexing over and over, then you may instead assume without loss of generality that the factors of each are listed in monotone nondecreasing order--that is, that $p_i\leq p_{i+1}$ whenever $1\leq i\leq r-1$ and $q_j\leq q_{j+1}$ whenever $1\leq j\leq s-1.$

Many thanks for both the nice example of distinct factorizations and also for avoiding the re-indexing over and over.

You're welcome!
